# Order "Entries Fields" by entry order

Tags: ordering, entries-field

I want to order entries in an "Entries field" by the order I added them to the field. So Anastasia would be first and Beni would be last.

[image]

My only idea was `.fixedOrder` like you would do it with an asset field:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('musiker').relatedTo(entry).fixedOrder(true) %}
   {{ entry.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But that does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it seems like you just want to list entries straight from the entries field. If that's the case, you won't need to use the [relatedTo param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param). Give this code a try:

```
{% for entry in entry.fieldHandle %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: :D Ooops. You are right. My code is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Kaspar The relatedTo param would have been ideal if, for example you wanted to find which entries have 'Anastasia' in the 'Musiker' entry field. But yes in this instance, a simple for loop is all that's needed :)

Answer (score 3):

It's `order('sortOrder')` instead of `fixedOrder(true)`.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: entry, field: 'entriesFieldHandle' },
    order: 'sortOrder',
    limit: null
}) %}
```

If you don't make any further modifications to the params (i.e. reverse order, other limit) there's also the short syntax for the above that Jamie already suggested:

```
{% set entries = entry. entriesFieldHandle %}
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave a error. I guess it was due to the related param. But no it's no longer needed.

Comment: Ahh that's strange, because I shamelessly copied it from [the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields#templating).

Comment: Yes. I did the same. Thats Why I asked in the first place. I thought `sortOrder` must be a placeholder then.